# Create a real time web application using .net framework and azure - very confused

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, real-time

Let us say I would like a simple (yet complex) web application where there is continuous READING AND WRITING to the sql azure database. Let us say I am tracking a location, and I would like it to be updated very frequently (lets take the worst case: 1 second).

From the little knowledge I have, I think that this involves the use of the database to continuously write the location to the database, and continuously read from the database to update another person through a website.

Do you please have any suggestion which technologies can I use? Is there a simple way? I heard about node.js, signalR. I have no idea how to use them, if they are really what I need. the last tutorial I checked out simply uses a while(true) loop..but I don't think that that's something good to keep a thread continuously busy...

Do I have to create some background task?

Do I have to create some web service?

This is a school project and I wish not to go for the most difficult option, but if there is some sort of solution, challenge accepted :)

Can you please help me? Since I have asked many questions here and yet I have no solution in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little old, but take a look at this case study:

Responding to high numbers of deaths at sea in the fishing industry, the Royal National Lifeboat Institution contracted Active Web Solutions (AWS) to create an automated sea-safety application. AWS developed a location-based service infrastructure, code-named GeoPoint, which transmits position data to a centralized tracking and alerting system. AWS used GeoPoint to build MOB Guardian, a search-and-rescue application for fishing vessels. To extend GeoPoint to more scenarios, AWS migrated it to the Windows Azure™ platform. By hosting GeoPoint in the “cloud,” in Microsoft® data centers, AWS attained massive scalability, richer functionality, and lower infrastructure costs. AWS was able to quickly convert its application to a hosted service and avoid the expense of building and managing a data center. AWS also has the flexibility and scalability to offer GeoPoint to many more markets.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benriga/archive/2009/12/29/windows-azure-lessons-learned-active-web-solutions.aspx

http://www.globalalerting.com/assets/a/w/aws_windowsazure_cs.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an ntier architecture, then the SignalR is a easy process...

build a chache object in App layer that cache the updates from all users...

then run a timer(start it from ApplicationStartup) in App layer that will check and update cache from database in a periodic way...

then use SignalR in WebServer to monitor user responses...

when a user updates his/her status... signal simply gets the data from cache and pushes the updates to all/selected users

Comment: can you please provide me with very basic tutorials so than I can learn to read and write to the database? Yes I am using a Data Business and Presentation Layer

Answer (score 0):

Can't I simply create a listener which raises my own events once a new notification, a new location is created in the database? With this all I would need to do is then push this data to the client. That is where signalR comes in :)